# Add a legend to a hierchical bar chart in D3

Tags: javascript, r, d3.js, charts

I have a hierarchical bar chart in D3 with two "levels" of data and I want to display a legend with two distinct items.

When a user clicks on a bar chart value X to go down to the next level, I want the value of X (i.e. a string) to appear in a legend on that new chart. That way, a user always knows what value/category they just clicked on.

The second part of the legend is that I want the aggregate count of all the values on a chart to show somewhere. So if I have a chart with values of 10,15,25 I want to be able to display 50 within a legend on the chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll asumme your are working with this: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1283663

first add text:

```
  var parent = svg.append("text").attr("x",-margin.left).attr("y",0)
```

On **down** function update the text:

```
  parent.text("Position:"+d.name+" Value:"+d.value)
```

and **up** function:

```
  parent.text("Position:"+d.parent.name+" Value:"+d.parent.value)
```

Here the [working code](https://plnkr.co/edit/c2TMHV1tHNCGxEOnpbqJ?p=preview)

If you don't want to show the root:

**down** function:

```
  if (d.name == "flare") {
    parent.text("")
  } else {
  parent.text("Position:"+d.name+" Value:"+d.value)  
  }
```

**up** function:

```
  if (d.parent.name == "flare") {
    parent.text("")
  } else {
  parent.text("Position:"+d.name+" Value:"+d.parent.value)  
  }
```

To show value after each name bars, tweak function bar(d):

```
  bar.append("text")
      .attr("x", -6)
      .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name+" : "+d.value; }); // <-- Here made mods
```

Comment: Very interesting approach. How would you modify it so that it didn't show the new text element when the chart is first opened? I want the text element to be blank initially and then only change when the user clicks on the bar.

Comment: "Flare" its the root. Simple empty name from the root or you can add a condition if (root) then don't show.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I'm accustomed to D3 being so complex that I love how straightforward this is.

Comment: yeah .. sometimes D3 can go out of control. Alway try to keep it simple and reuse